# Sort Totals By Months

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I need to show the count of all rows grouped by month and then pivot it
Appreciate an easy solution for that

Or alternatively if someone can help me fix this

I've used dynamic pivot query

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, createDate)))
                      FROM OSCL
                      WHERE     ([status] = - 3) 

                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query =

'SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    callID,
    DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, createDate)) as Months
  FROM OSCL
  WHERE     ([status] = - 3) 
) AS t
PIVOT 
(
  COUNT(callID) 
  FOR Months IN( ' + @cols + ' )' +
' ) AS p ; ';

 execute(@query);
```

This gives me data like this

```
April | February | March
44    | 1        | 5
```

But, I want to show in Sequence

```
January | February | March | April (Till the current month)
0       | 1        | 5     | 44
```

Table Example Is This
For Example

```
callID   |   U_Regn   |   createDate
```

What I Want To Show Is
A Calendar

```
             January | February | March | April 
Database1 |   0      | 1        | 5     | 44
Database2 |   0      | 6        | 6     | 6
```

Comment: Create a table with all months than RIGHT JOIN it with OSCL so that all months will appear,than use COALESCE to make NULL into 0

Comment: Mihai is on the right track. Join your derived pivot table, `p`, to an derived table with 1 to 12 and the month name. Order by month_number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                    QUOTENAME(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, createDate)))
                  FROM OSCL
                  WHERE     ([status] = - 3) 

                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                    , 1, 1, '');
```

to

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' +
                    QUOTENAME(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, createDate)))
                  FROM OSCL
                  WHERE     ([status] = - 3)
                  GROUP BY QUOTENAME(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, createDate))), DATEPART(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, createDate))
                  ORDER BY DATEPART(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, createDate))

                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                    , 1, 1, '');
```